# Preventing scroll to a non-programmatically focused element

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus

I have a table with some sticky columns. In the first column, there's a checkbox. The problem is that whenever I focus a checkbox (with tab or simply clicking on it), my table scrolls to the left. I understand why it happens - the browser wants to make sure a focused checkbox is in the viewport. But since for me it's always in the viewport (sticky), this behavior doesn't help.

I know that it can be done for programmatically-driven focus:

```js
element.focus({ preventScroll: true });
```

But how about the default focus handled by the browser?

Comment: Not sure about the default focus handled by the browser, but how about hiding the table initially, showing a spinner or something similar and only showing it once your JS has kicked in?

Comment: @skashi How is this relevant? :)

Comment: It gets your table to show without it jumping initially

Comment: @skashi I don't think you understood what this question is about.